# How did 'Classified' get so messed up?

Tags: military

The military is usually pretty good about terminology and has handily invented lots of it.

But when it comes to 'Classified'... yikes.  It's just awful.

What I mean, in case it isn't obvious, is that 'classified' can be a verb and 'Classified' (which is not commonly capitalized, but I'm trying to maintain modicum of sanity in here) is a level of classification.

So a document might be classified as Classified, or it might be classified as Unclassified, or it might be unclassified.

Or a document previously classified as Classified might be declassified so now it is classified as Unclassified.

How did such a abominable situation come to exist and persist?

Comment: Have you tried the usual recommended resources?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Good idea. A stiff drink is always helpful.

Comment: "Classified" isn't a classification.  "Confidential", "secret", and "top secret" are.  (And I suspect that there is one higher than "top secret", but I wouldn't want to ask.)

Comment: @HotLicks You forgot "Restricted" (old-style) or "Official" (new-style) below "Confidential".

Comment: @HotLicks As a former military with "top secret security clearance", I could tell you, but then I would have to kill you. No hard feelings.

Comment: @Cascabel - There are people working in private industry that are in the same situation.

Comment: @HotLicks is right. There is no classification  called  "Classified" that I know of, except possibly in the movies. In the military, even Algebra II books get classified as "Confidential", and my former texts on what were the Fukishima plants is still classified "Top Secret" although out-of-date 40 years ago.

Comment: @Mick 'classified', not 'glassified'.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth Nice timing. I just poured myself a rum and coke. Cheers!

Comment: @Mick It'll soon be 'glassy-eyed'. Cheers; I can't, sadly, mix such potions with the ones doctors provide. Beyond about 6 units per week.

Comment: @Mick Try our national Botran Solera...top shelf.

Comment: All of the above is correct, which is not in any way to suggest that it *isn't* really messed up.

Comment: @PhilSweet - Yep, I had to fill out four pages of application -- TWICE -- to get a "confidential" clearance, then got a "secret" clearance without even knowing it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing is classified as "Classified". Things (generally information) are classified at some level, say as "Secret", "Top Secret", plus perhaps "NOFORN", "SCI" or "SAP" etc.  When talking about some information and trying to indicate it's not to be discussed openly one might refer to it (the information) as "Classified".

OK:
"Hey, what's the top speed of that new jet?"

"Sorry, that's classified."

Telling someone some information being asked about is "Top Secret", etc.,  is against the rules. So one must simply say, "It's classified". In other words, the actual classification is classified.

Not OK:
"Hey, what's the top speed of that new jet?"

"Sorry, that's Top Secret."

The very fact that the info is "Top Secret" rather than simply "Secret" indicates a higher level of sensitivity, which could be interpreted as meaning that's one really special jet.

Comment: And now that you told us this you have to kill us.

Comment: Actually @HotLicks that decision is classified.